# Get stylelint fix to work with styled-components in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, styled-components, stylelint

Anyone know of any plugin or any way of getting VSCode stylelint autofix when using styled-components?

Comment: As mentioned in https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#setup stylelint auto-fix does not work with styled-components.

Answer (score 1):

update 2022: you can use [vscode-styled-components](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components) for :

- Syntax highlighting for styled components in JavaScript and TypeScript.
- Detailed CSS IntelliSense while working in styled strings.
- Syntax error reporting.

Comment: As of Feb 2022, this is the correct link https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components

Answer (score 1):

We can use [stylelint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint) and in VS Code config add: "stylelint.validate": ["typescript", "typescriptreact", ...]

The default is: "stylelint.validate": ["css", "postcss"]